# How does angular resolve controllers defined in modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking at the [angular documentation for controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) there's something that confuses me. Let's say someone does this:

```
angular.module('foo').controller('controller1', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
});
```

and:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='controller1'>
</div>
```

How does angular know that *'controller1'* resides in module *'foo'*?

And furthermore if someone does this in addition:

```
angular.module('bar').controller('controller1', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
});
```

Which one will angular chose now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `ng-app` here:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='controller1'>
</div>
```

Angular will look for a module definition with the name `app`.  Something like this:

```
angular.module('app', []);  // notice the []
```

Inside the second parameter `[]` array, Angular wants the *dependent* modules.  So, in order to include `controller1` from `foo` module, you would do this:

```
angular.module('app', ['foo']);
```

And from the `bar` module:

```
angular.module('app', ['bar']);
```

In each of these, there is only a single `controller1` named controller.

So, what happens when you register both the `foo` and `bar` modules?  I would think that the last one wins.  So, if you define `app` to be:

```
angular.module('app', ['foo', 'bar']);
```

Then, the `bar` module's `controller1` will overwrite the name `controller1` inside the injector.

So, there is no built-in mechanism that allows for the same name to be applied across modules.  Because of this, you can employ naming schemes to make sure that the controller is unique:

```
angular.module('bar').controller('bar.controller1', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
});
```

> How does angular know that 'controller1' resides in module 'foo'?

At the time that Angular is resolving `controller1`, it doesn't know what module it is in.  Once the module is a dependent (on the module defined in `ng-app`), all of the controllers (in all modules) are only resolved off of their names.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't really know where the controller comes from. Your application includes either `foo` or `bar` and then `controller1` is registered.

If you include both `foo` and `bar` `controller1` is from whatever module you included last.